# Switching between two datasets in this d3.js reusable and zoomable line chart

Tags: jquery, plot, d3.js, code-reuse

In this example http://bl.ocks.org/4743409 I set up a zoomable line chart containing two lines.

[image: d3 lne chart]

But Switching the selection `options` I obtain a superposition of the two datasets. How can I switch between the two?

Thank you in advance for your help and most of all for your suggestions to improve the code.

**UPDATE:**  I succeeded in implementing a reusable chart (and I updated the example in the link). Now I have no superposition of the two datasets. However, I still do not understand why the proper `svg` dimesions are only setted on update and not on the first creation.