# D3: How to refresh a chart with new data?

Tags: d3.js

I have created a d3 donut chart. Here is my code:

```
var width = 480;
var height = 480;
var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
var doughnutWidth = 30;

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
.outerRadius(radius - 10)
.innerRadius(radius - 70);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
.sort(null)
.value(function(d) { return d[1]; });

var dataset = settings.dataset;
console.log(dataset);

var svg = d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var path = svg.selectAll('path')
.data(pie(dataset))
.enter()
.append('path')
.attr('d', arc)
.attr('fill', function(d, i) { 
  return color(d.data[0]);
})
```

I have a simple form on my web page which displays a dropdown menu with several options. Every time a user changes a value on the form a new dataset is sent to my script (settings.dataset) and the donut is redrawn on the page.

Problem is, some of the values from the previous dataset remain in the DOM. In the console output below, you can see that the second dataset only has two elements. The third one is from the previous dataset. This is messing up the chart, as it is displaying a value that shouldn't be there.

[image]

My question: how do I clear the old values? I've read up on `.exit()` and `.remove()`, but I can't get my head around these methods.

Comment: so the code you have pasted above gets executed everytime on udate?

Comment: Yes, the script is called everytime a user chooses a different option on my form.

Comment: one issue i can see is d3.select("body")
.append("svg") that means you are appending the svg everytime on update. do d3.select("svg").remove() to ensure its removed on update.

Comment: Add that line to the top of the script?

Comment: before teh line var svg = d3.select("body")
.append("svg")

Comment: No change. Same result.The 'dataset' array still has too many elements.

Comment: Here's a pretty good tutorial: http://jonsadka.com/blog/how-to-create-adaptive-pie-charts-with-transitions-in-d3/

Comment: Not sure if it helps but consider looking into [reusable d3 charts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665786/some-clarification-on-reusable-charts) if you're looking to create charts with loading different datasets. Here's an example of a [reusable donut chart](http://bl.ocks.org/nnattawat/9368297). Had a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23031671/d3-js-loading-different-json-datasets-on-dropdown-change) some time back.

Answer (score 30):

Create one function that (re)draws the pie when it's created and when it's updated.

New data should be added to pie using `enter()` and old data should be removed using `exit().remove()`

It is as simple as this:

```
  path.enter().append("path")
            .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
            .attr("d", arc)
            .each(function(d) {this._current = d;} );

  path.transition()
            .attrTween("d", arcTween);

  path.exit().remove()
```

Full working code -> [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nrndh3cn/)

Comment: What does `.each(function (d) {this._current = d;})` do?

Comment: How do we do this for a react component? If i'm passing a prop to the sunburst component to control which level of zoom the sunburst is at. I need a way to only update the render and not re-render the entire component.

Answer (score 12):

There are two steps to implement the 'redraw' effect you want:

First, I suppose you want the svg canvas to be drawn only once when the page is loaded for the first time, and then update the chart in the svg instead of remove and redraw the svg:

```
 var svg = d3.select("body")
              .selectAll("svg")
              .data([settings.dataset]);  
 // put data in an array with only one element

 // this ensures there is only one consistent svg on the page when data is updated(when the script gets executed) 
 svg.enter().append("svg")
```

Second, understanding `enter()`, `exit()`, there are many great tutorials about this. In your case, I would suggest to draw the donut something like this:

```
var path = svg.selectAll(".donut")  
           .data(settings.data)

// bind data to elements, now you have elements belong to one of those 
// three 'states', enter, exit, or update

// for `enter` selection, append elements
path.enter().append("path").attr("d", arc).attr("fill", "teal")

// for `update` selection, which means they are already binded with data
path.transition().attrTween("d", someFunction) // apply transition here if you want some animation for data change

// for `exit` selection, they shouldn't be on the svg canvas since there is no corresponding data, you can then remove them
 path.exit().remove()
```

Comment: I take your point: draw the chart once and then update according to the user selection. A bit like this: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346410. At the moment I'm only loading the data the user is interested in. In this approach I need to load all the data and store in a larger array - which is not a big problem because it's a small amount of data. I'll have to rewrite the code that delivers the data. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Redrawing chart each time would suit my use case better, I think.

Comment: If you whant you meant is to remove and re-append path each time, transition() and exit() won't be necessary then

Comment: In the console output in my question, the first output is from the drawing of my first donut. It is correct, there are three values. The second output is a new donut, it should have just two values (anonymous and johnd), but it contains a third value, Blog 3, from the first donut. I need to remove this value before the second donut gets drawn.

Comment: @24ma13wg Looks like the problem is caused by `settings.dataset`, not much to do with d3 drawing, could you please add more code on how to get `settings.dataset`?

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. I don't think my D3 script is the issue.

Answer (score 10):

```
//remove and create svg
d3.select("svg").remove(); 
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width","960").attr("height", "600"),
inner = svg.append("g");
```