# exit().remove() not working in my D3.js Force Layout Graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've created a simple D3 Force Layout graph. [Please check it out in the JSFiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/Imray/grewqy39/4/)

The graph is very basic - it features cities as nodes connected to nodes representing the ocuntry they are in. For simplicity, I've made only six nodes.

[image: D3JS Graph]

I've created a function called `deleteNodeOnClick()` and set it on the `nodes` like this

```
 var nodeEnter = node.enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'node')
        .on("click", deleteNodeOnClick)
```

When you click on a node in the graph, that node gets removed from the data (actually for simplicity the first node gets removed from the data for now) **however it does not get removed from the visual graph**. You can look in the console and see that it is in fact removed from the data.

**Why not?** I am completely stumped.

## The Code

```
var data = {
  nodes: [{
    name: "Canada"
  }, {
    name: "Montreal"
  }, {
    name: "Toronto"
  }, {
    name: "USA"
  }, {
    name: "New York"
  }, {
    name: "Los Angeles"
  }],
  links: [{
    source: 0,
    target: 1
  }, {
    source: 0,
    target: 2
  }, {
    source: 3,
    target: 4
  }, {
    source: 3,
    target: 5
  }, ]
};

var node;
var link;
var force;
var width = 400,
  height = 400;
  
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", window.innerWidth)
    .attr("height", window.innerHeight);

force = d3.layout.force()
  .size([width, length])
  .nodes(data.nodes)
  .links(data.links)
  .gravity(.1)
  .alpha(0.01)
  .charge(-400)
  .friction(0.5)
  .linkDistance(100)
  .on('tick', forceLayoutTick);

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
  .data(data.links);
var linkEnter = link.enter()
  .append('line')
  .attr('class', 'link');
link.exit().remove();

node = svg.selectAll('.node')
        .data(data.nodes, function(d){
            return d.name;
        });

    node.exit().remove();

    var nodeEnter = node.enter()
                        .append('g')
                        .attr('class', 'node')
                        .on("click", deleteNodeOnClick)
                        //.attr('r', 8)
                        //.attr('cx', function(d, i){ return (i+1)*(width/4); })
                        //.attr('cy', function(d, i){ return height/2; })
                        .call(force.drag);

  nodeEnter
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", 0)
        .attr("cy", 0)
        .attr("r", 10)
        .style("fill", "purple");

    nodeEnter
        .append("text")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name })
        .attr("class", "label")
        .attr("dx", 0)
        .attr("dy", ".35em");
        
 force.start();
 
 
 function forceLayoutTick(){
            
            node.attr("transform", function(d) {
                    
                // Keep in bounding box
                d.x = Math.max(10, Math.min(width - 10, d.x)); 
                d.y = Math.max(10, Math.min(height - 10, d.y));

                return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; 
            });

            link
                .attr('x1', function(d){ return d.source.x; })
                .attr('y1', function(d){ return d.source.y; })
                .attr('x2', function(d){ return d.target.x; })
        
                .attr('y2', function(d){ return d.target.y; });
    };
    
    function deleteNodeOnClick(d){
        var dataBefore = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.nodes));
        // Just delete the first node, for demonstration purposes
      data.nodes.splice(0, 1);
      console.info("Node should be removed", dataBefore, data.nodes);
    }
```

### CSS

```
#graph {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#graph svg {
  background-color: #CCC;
}

.link {
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke: black;
}

.node {
  background-color: darkslategray;
  stroke: #138;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  pointer-events: none;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.label {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at how to refresh d3.js charts yet? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34088550/d3-how-to-refresh-a-chart-with-new-data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In D3, changing the data doesn't *automagically* change the SVG (or canvas, or HTML...) elements. You have to "repaint" your dataviz.

The good news is that you have (almost) all the selections. So, just to show you the general idea, I put all the rendering code inside a `draw` function, which is called on click:

```
function deleteNodeOnClick(d){
    data.nodes = data.nodes.filter(function(e){
        return e.name !== d.name;
    });
    draw();
}
```

Check the demo:

```js
var data = {
    nodes: [{
        name: "Canada"
    }, {
        name: "Montreal"
    }, {
        name: "Toronto"
    }, {
        name: "USA"
    }, {
        name: "New York"
    }, {
        name: "Los Angeles"
    }],
    links: [{
        source: 0,
        target: 1
    }, {
        source: 0,
        target: 2
    }, {
        source: 3,
        target: 4
    }, {
        source: 3,
        target: 5
    }, ]
};

var node;
var link;
var force;
var width = 400,
    height = 400;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);



draw();

function draw() {

    force = d3.layout.force()
        .size([width, height])
        .nodes(data.nodes)
        .links(data.links)
        .alpha(0.01)
        .charge(-400)
        .friction(0.5)
        .linkDistance(100)
        .on('tick', forceLayoutTick);

    var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
        .data(data.links);
    var linkEnter = link.enter()
        .append('line')
        .attr('class', 'link');
    link.exit().remove();

    node = svg.selectAll('.node')
        .data(data.nodes, function(d) {
            return d.name;
        });

    node.exit().remove();

    var nodeEnter = node.enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'node')
        .on("click", deleteNodeOnClick)
        //.attr('r', 8)
        //.attr('cx', function(d, i){ return (i+1)*(width/4); })
        //.attr('cy', function(d, i){ return height/2; })
        .call(force.drag);

    nodeEnter
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", 0)
        .attr("cy", 0)
        .attr("r", 10)
        .style("fill", "purple");

    nodeEnter
        .append("text")
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.name
        })
        .attr("class", "label")
        .attr("dx", 0)
        .attr("dy", ".35em");

    force.start();


    function forceLayoutTick() {

        node.attr("transform", function(d) {

            // Keep in bounding box
            d.x = Math.max(10, Math.min(width - 10, d.x));
            d.y = Math.max(10, Math.min(height - 10, d.y));

            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        });

        link
            .attr('x1', function(d) {
                return d.source.x;
            })
            .attr('y1', function(d) {
                return d.source.y;
            })
            .attr('x2', function(d) {
                return d.target.x;
            })

        .attr('y2', function(d) {
            return d.target.y;
        });
    };

};

function deleteNodeOnClick(d) {
    data.nodes = data.nodes.filter(function(e) {
        return e.name !== d.name;
    });
    draw();
}
```

```css
#graph svg {
  background-color: #CCC;
}

.link {
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke: black;
}

.node {
  background-color: darkslategray;
  stroke: #138;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  pointer-events: none;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<body></body>
```

Of course, as I said, that is just to give you the general idea: for instance, the click doesn't remove the links. But now you know how to put it to work.

Comment: Thanks this is cool. I'm surprised draw needs to be called every time there is a change. From what I read about D3 I thought the whole advantage of it was that you can bind data to visuals and it updates when changes are made.

Comment: No, it doesn't, whoever said that to you was wrong. Changing the data is only that: a change in the data bound to the element. There are some libraries built on top of d3, though, that automatically update the chart when you change the data.

Comment: Ok that is a bit disappointing. I'm wondering, if I am creating a new `d3.layout.force()` each time I call `draw`, why don't I see it rendering again, as I do the first time? What tells it "don't draw this again from scratch you already have something on the screen"?

Comment: The force definition can be outside the draw function, I wrote that in a hurry yesterday, as I told you, just to show you the general idea. That code in my answer *is not* the best or optimal code. But pay attention to this: we have two different things here, the force just reposition the nodes. To make the nodes appear/disappear, you need a enter/update/exit selection.

Answer (score 0):

Your function does not do anything to the graph: (just the data)

```
function deleteNodeOnClick(d){
    var dataBefore = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.nodes));
    // Just delete the first node, for demonstration purposes
    data.nodes.splice(0, 1);
    console.info("Node should be removed", dataBefore, data.nodes);
}
```

re-render or remove from the graph...

Example, just to remove (specific) "dot"

```
function deleteNodeOnClick(d) {
  var theElement = node.filter(function(da, i) {
      if (i === d.index) {
        console.log(da);
        return true;
      }
    })
  console.dir(theElement);
  theElement.remove();
  var dataBefore = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.nodes));
  // Just delete the first node, for demonstration purposes
  data.nodes.splice(d.index, 1);
  console.info("Node should be removed", dataBefore, data.nodes);
}
```

Note that does NOT remove the "line" connecting the OTHER node, I will leave that exercise up to you to do.

More compact version without all the logging etc.

```
function deleteNodeOnClick(d) {
   d3.select(node[0][d.index]).remove();
   data.nodes.splice(d.index, 1);
 }
```

(added for OTHERS visiting this site)
For d3 version 4 this would be

```
function deleteNodeOnClick(d) {
   d3.select(node._groups[0][d.index]).remove();
   data.nodes.splice(d.index, 1);
 }
```

Comment: Isn't the point of data binding that when the data changes the graph changes? Wasn't that the point of `.data(...)`?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean `re-render` the graph? Is there a command for that?

Comment: Added example update (pretty ugly but a start point) Note that i really do not like your choice of "node"  name variable but that is just opinion...

Comment: I added a simpler version as well, once again no remove of the line connect.